# Exchange 2010 Public folder

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2011

I've been having a problem for the last few days with a client we have just started providing support for.  Bit of history, client was hit with Cryptolocker virus, and through trying to restore everything (including paying the ransom!!!), previous support ended up moving their email to Office 365. Unfortunately I don't have many more details about that. We are trying to move them back to Exchange as the server is still relatively new.  Server is SBS 2011.

Mailbox setup and move has been fine.  Problem I am having is Public Folders, when I try and access them from Outlook 2010 I get the following:
"Cannot expand the folder.  The attempt to log on to Microsoft Exchange has failed."

If I Test E-mail Autoconfiguration, here are the results:

[image]

In the 'Sync Issues' folder in Outlook I have two message with the same contents:

17:00:11 Synchronizer Version 14.0.7157
17:00:11 Synchronizing Mailbox 'User'
17:00:11 Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Calendar'
17:00:11 Downloading from server 'Servername.domain.local'
17:00:11       1 view(s)/form(s) added to offline folder
17:00:12         Could not connect to public folder server.
17:00:12         [8004011D-512-476-0]
17:00:12         The attempt to log on to Microsoft Exchange has failed.
17:00:12         Microsoft Exchange Information Store
17:00:12         For more information on this failure, click the URL below:

I've been scouring the web the last couple days and every post I follow sends me down the wrong path for one reason or another.  Usually I take what I read and compare with some of our other clients SBS2011 servers and I have yet to find something different.

Alot of article refer to autodiscover address, yes when I compare the DNS console on other clients servers, everything appears the same as this one here.

One interesting note, if I dismount the Public Folder Store and then remount it, I can access it from Outlook for maybe 30 seconds and then the problem returns

Any help anyone can provide would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you move the mailboxe/public folders back to on-prem? Do you also happen to know how they were migrated to O365 in the first place?
I am assuming the users are now using their SBS2011 mailboxes.
If you open the PF console from EMC, can you browse through the PF structure?
CTRL+right click on the Outlook icon in the system tray and run test autoconfiguration for one of the users. In the resulting XML you should have some details about the Public Folders.
Are there any errors/warnings in the event viewer?

Comment: We moved the mailboxes back the long way, exporting their Office 365 accounts to PST, including the 'Shared' mailbox (that's where the Public Folders were moved to) and then imported them into their Exchange Mailboxes.  I was not able to browse the PF structure, unfortunately I don't have a record of the error message.   I had posted a link to a screen shot of the Email Autoconfiguration results from Outlook, but it appears it was edited out, I do know the XML tab was empty.

Answer (score 0):

While googling and searching different forums for various app log and outlook errors I was seeing, most post referenced a scenario of an exchange migration somehow.  We keyed in on this and finally found the answer

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150486%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

In particular the Shell command:
 Set-OrganizationConfig -PublicFoldersLockedForMigration:$False